# Why does Windows 8 randomly start using a proxy server for LAN?

Tags: networking, windows-8, proxy

To make it clear what the issue is: In Control Panel > Internet Options > Connections > LAN settings > Proxy server, Windows enables the "Use a proxy server for your LAN" option after a power cycle and seemingly randomly on other occasions

I say random but it happens mostly if there's a power outage that causes an unexpected shut down. I'm not sure of any other identifiable cases when it happens.

[image]

1. Why does Windows do this? I've never used any kind of proxy for any reason, ever.
2. How do I stop Windows from doing this? It's a bit of a pain because this is my work laptop and the vast majority of my work is online; this setting being enabled blocks my online access so I have to go an uncheck the box before I can work.

Answer (score 0):

That is not enabled and that allows you to use a proxy server for your LAN. However you can disable it for your computer using registry. Open registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` in Registry editor. Change value of `ProxySettingsPerUser` value to 1. If it does not exist then create it and set value to 1.